# Declaring variables outside of functional React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it OK to declare a variable outside of a functional React component such as:

```
const outsideVariable = new Map([['key', 'value']])
const ComponentName = props => (
  <div>
    Some Text
  </div>
)

export default ComponentName
```

Comment: I defiantly don't want to mutate it once it has been created.

Comment: I think you mean _definitely_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - as long as you don't mutate it. Because when you mutate it, your component is stateful and no longer functional.

Comment: they are called functional components because they are created by defining a function

Comment: @IsaacCWay Right. But if they didn't intend both meanings, react creators really messed up their terminology. They still emphasise that render functions should be pure.

Comment: In the context of React, a functional component is just a component that is a function. A *component* being functional or not has nothing to do with whether it is or isn't pure, and if you want to claim that the React developers for some reason named them functional components for some reason other than the fact they're literally a function, you'll certainly need a source for that. React is a library, not a framework, it does not have opinions on how it should be used.

Comment: @IsaacCWay Looking at the react homepage, it seems the official term is actually "**function** component". (Maybe they changed this in an effort to disambiguate? I don't know.) And [right from the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect): "*side effects are not allowed inside the main body of a function component (referred to as React’s render phase).  […] Think of [`useEffect`] as an escape hatch from React’s purely functional world into the imperative world.*" When they use the term "functional", they refer to FP.